# Compilation fails due to prototype cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I have a TableViewController subclass with one prototype cell designed in storyboard. Then I am passing the references to the class header etc and for some reason it fails to compile it. But the connections seem fine. I provide you the code and pictures of the build errors and the storyboard. I am using Xcode 4.3.3. Any help is really appreciated.

**favTable.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface favTable : UITableViewController  <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> 
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
   NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

    NSArray *favArr;
    NSMutableArray *favName;
    NSMutableArray *favScore;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *favArr;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *favName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *favScore;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;




@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *celldes;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellimage;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellname;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellmanu;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellscore;



@end
```

**favTable.m**

```
#import "favTable.h"
#import "ecoAppDelegate.h"



@interface favTable ()


@end

@implementation favTable

@synthesize favArr;

@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize favName;
@synthesize favScore;


@synthesize celldes;
@synthesize cellimage;
@synthesize cellname;
@synthesize cellmanu;
@synthesize cellscore;



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Favorites";


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;




    // passing the array of addedtofavorites to the total one with all favorites



    self.managedObjectContext = ((ecoAppDelegate *) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).managedObjectContext;



    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"FavoritesInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", nil]];



      NSError *error=nil;

    self.favArr=[[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]mutableCopy];


    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@" fetchError=%@,details=%@",error,error.userInfo); 
    }


    self.favName = [[self.favArr valueForKey:@"name"] mutableCopy];
    self.favScore = [[self.favArr valueForKey:@"score"] mutableCopy];



}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setCelldes:nil];
    [self setCellimage:nil];
    [self setCellname:nil];
    [self setCellmanu:nil];
    [self setCellscore:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [favName count];;
}





- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

         // Configure the cell...

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

cellname.text = @"Test";

    return cell;
}






@end
```

[image: Storyboard and connections]

[image: Build Errors]

Comment: Have you set the table cell identifier in storyboard as "Cell"?

Comment: @Student Yes already done that

Comment: "self.favArr=[[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]mutableCopy];" Why using mutableCopy in this line if favArr is an NSArray not NSMutableArray?

Comment: @Student This doesn't influence this problem. I tried setting it up with simple literal strings instead but it still has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

- I moved manually the IB outlets into a separate custom cell class and then linked the references to the storyboard (maybe this is fixed in newer versions)
- Then applied that cell style in the prototype cell and simply changed the content of the UI items of my cell using the identifier (no tag was needed)